# Why blender render produce different data even if input data is the same.

Tags: python, blender-internal-render-engine

Why blender render produce different data even if input data is the same. I mean, i am trying to compare two images rendered by blender, they are identical overall, but the value differs in 3-7 bytes (if work with an image as with byte array)

Comment: Date/timestamp? Rendertime? Presumably some metadata. Update your question to add more detail - such as details of how/where you spotted the differences. This is too vague as it stands.